# How to set up dns on (l)ubuntu livecd?

Tags: ubuntu, networkmanager

The first thing I have done was remove resolvconf cause it was block chattr +i on /etc/resolv.conf
But even this not helped.
After install on desktop, resolv.conf is generated by NetworkManager (so why chattr not work?) with nameserver 127.0.1.1
I'm not sure where to set default one.

Comment: This is unclear and confusing. What are you trying to accomplish? (“Set up DNS” isn't specific enough!) What's up with `chattr`; are you _trying_ to `chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf`; if so, why?

Comment: Well my bad. Of course I was trying to lock this file exactly this way. But at first it failed cause `resolvconf` has locked resolv.conf.

Comment: Why are you trying to prevent modifications to `/etc/resolv.conf`? We want to get to the _root_ of what you're trying to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally its working!
First `apt-get remove resolvconf`
Second `pico /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and comment line starting with `dns`
Third edit `/etc/resolv.conf` as You need.

After install everything is working fine.

And strange fact. Installation process is ignoring somehow `chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf`.